# Parallel execution on specflow xunit

Tags: azure-devops, xunit, specflow

I am looking to maximize the parallel execution of Specflow + Xunit, currently the parallel is up to the feature level. I am looking for a way to make it up to scenario level. I do plan to use specflow+runner, unfortunately it has stopped development.

Currently I did the workaround using DevOps pipeline to distribute the scenarios to 2 agents. Does someone have any better suggestions?

```
Calculator.feature

  Feature: Calculator
   Scenario: Add two numbers
   ...

   @agent2 // Assign to agent 2
   Scenario: Add two numbers 2
   ...

Calculator2.feature

  Feature: Calculator2
   Scenario: Add two numbers 3
   ...
   
   @agent2 // Assign to agent 2
   Scenario: Add two numbers 4
   ...
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation of xUnit. From [Running Tests in Parallel on xunit.net](https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel):

> #### Test Collections
>
> How does xUnit.net decide which tests can run against each other in parallel? It uses a concept called test collections to make that decision.
>
> By default, each test class is a unique test collection. **Tests within the same test class will not run in parallel against each other.**

(emphasis, mine)

A feature file in SpecFlow gets parsed and converted to a test class in xUnit. A test class (and therefore a feature file in SpecFlow) become default collections to support parallelization when running tests. Until xUnit supports a way to run test methods in the same class in parallel, this does not appear possible when using xUnit + SpecFlow, because it is not possible when just using xUnit.